# exclude some ids associated to determined condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

In the following code I am looking forward to extract the ids associated to accounts with a determined status.

There are 4 status (Active, Inactive, Closed, Verifying)
Almost every account is associated to a phone and one phone could be associated to various accounts, for example:

- A phone could be associated to various accounts, 1 Active, 1 inactive and let's say maybe another closed (lets call this account A).
- Account B is only associated to a Closed account
- Account C is only associated to an Inactive account

With my code I am looking to identify those phones who are ONLY associated to accounts that are not active. I noticed that my code gives me back all phones associated to accounts like A, B and C (Because A is associated to at least 1 NOT 'Active' account), I just want phones associated to accounts like B and C, and exclude ALL type A (if the phone is linked to at least 1 Active account, I don't want it in my db)

```
select 
  phone.id,
  phone.number,
  account.status as status_account 
  max(date_trunc('day', accountstatuslog.modified)::date) as modif_account_date
from accountstatuslog
join account on account.id = accountstatuslog.account_id
join phone on phone.id = account.phone_id 
where 
  account.status not in ('Active') and
  accountstatuslog.status = account.status and
group by 
  account.status,
  account.phone_id
```

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, except those who are arguments to set functions. I.e. I'd try `GROUP BY phone.id, phone.number, account.status`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Anti-Join to eliminate the records that you want.
Anti-Join is efficient because it rejects a row at the first occurrence  of the value to eliminate.
Table:

```
postgres=# select * from PhoneStatus;
 phoneaccholder | accountstatus
----------------+---------------
 Vincent        | Active
 Vincent        | Inactive
 Xavier         | Active
 Benjamin       | Closed
 Sebastian      | Closed
 Gabriel        | Active
 Christopher    | Inactive
(7 rows)
```

SQL:

```
SELECT phoneaccholder
     ,accountstatus
 --  ,Count(*)
FROM   phonestatus x
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   phonestatus y
                   WHERE  y.accountstatus = 'Active'
                          AND x.phoneaccholder = y.phoneaccholder)
       and accountstatus in ('Closed','Inactive')
GROUP  BY accountstatus,
          phoneaccholder; 
   

Output:

  phoneaccholder | accountstatus
----------------+---------------
 Benjamin       | Closed
 Sebastian      | Closed
 Christopher    | Inactive
(3 rows)
```